# How do I number the equations locally?

Tags: equations, numbering

To write equations, I use the `\begin{align*}` ... `\end{align*}` commands. I type my equations inside it. I add lines of text or paragraphs in between using the command `\intertext`. Now my question is how do I number the equations selectively. I want to make it clear that I do not want to number all the equations. I want to number only certain selected equations in order. Please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace align* with align and use \nonumber for lines you do not want numbering.

Comment: `\notag` also works to suppress the number on selected lines.